# Trying to create a Javascript link within what I believe are variables?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, hyperlink

I downloaded a theme and seem to be having some trouble.  The page in question is here - http://pureearthsoaps.com/test.html

Each product is created using (if I've been explained correctly) Javascript variables.  See below:

```
  1: {
name: 'Bar Soap',
scent: 'Cucumber &amp; Oatmeal, Patchouli, Peppermint, Frankincense, Holiday, Coffee &amp; Hazelnut, Apple, and more',
size: '1 bar',
price: '3.<span class="small">95</span>',
short_desc: 'An innovative and moisturizing way to keep shower time fun.',
desc: 'Since we all love being happy naked, why not keep it that way? Treat yourself to scrumptious skincare with Naked Bar, an innovative and moisturizing way to keep shower time fun.'},
```

I enter the information here and it corresponds to the code here:

```
      __ += '<li id="wine-list-'+i+'">'+wines[i].name+',</li>';
  full += '<div id="wine-info-'+i+'" class="wine-info transition-05"><h2>'+wines[i].name+'</h2><h4></h4>'+
    '<div class="line"></div>'+
    '<div class="price">$'+wines[i].price+'</div>'+
    '<div class="lbl"><label>Scent:</label><span>'+wines[i].scent+'</span></div>'+
    '<div class="lbl"><label>Size:</label><span>'+wines[i].size+'</span></div>'+
    '<div class="img"></div>'+
    '<div class="bottle-x"></div>'+
    '<div class="desc">'+wines[i].desc+'</div>'+
    '<div class="order">'+wines[i].order+'</div>'+
  '</div>';
```

Currently, the "order now" button that shows up on that product page appears on each product, but cannot be linked.  The div class of "order" above was added at the advice of a coder friend; it makes the button appear, but we can't make it work.  I have added this below the "desc" line in the first code block with no luck:

```
    order: '<a  onClick="location.href='http://google.com'" href="http://google.com"></a>'
```

So... help!  How do I make this work?

Comment: Please don't edit relevant history out of your questions. This site exists to help *the next person* with the same question, too.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate problem of quotes has been addressed by the others. I will address some of the underlying problems in your code, that will help prevent mistakes in the future.

**Firstly**

```
var obj = {}
```

This is a JavaScript Object, specifically an object literal.

**Secondly**

JavaScript variables cannot start with or only be numbers, so `1 = {};` is invalid

Instead of assigning your objects to a number and iterating through them, generally what you want is an array of objects. So...

```
var wines = [{name:'wine', blah:'', ......}, {name:'second wine', ....}]
```

This way you can iterate through them in a loop whilst getting `wines[i]`, and your code will be valid :)

**Thirdly**

It is generally a good practice to try to reduce the amount of html that is written to the page by your js.

Why? It is way easier to debug, as an innerHTML/.html() can contain many statements. And it is also faster.

Try to have the elements on the page and write to them using `getElementById` and `textContent`, or use jquery's selector and `text()` or `html()`. If they need to be hidden, set them as hidden initally in your html/css, and modify that css property or class later with js.

**Finally**

Inline onClicks are so 90's. And will literally cause you headache's when you start double crossing strings.

Use jQuery's `on()` method or

```
document.getElementById('elem').onclick = function(){
   //Code here
};
```

Comment: I'm sure everything you've suggested is very sound, but I didn't write the code and honestly I don't have time to rewrite it.  I'm looking for a simple solution to add links to the order button, and I've implemented the other suggestions with no luck.

Comment: That code really needs some love, it is basically un-maintainable, and any future web devs will pull their hair out trying to work it out.

The problem is Line 326 in styles.css

Change `#wines-info .wines .active { opacity: 1; }` to `#wines-info .wines .active { opacity: 1; z-index=10;}`

Comment: Thank you so much!  This did it.  I had to do a little work to get the text link instead of an image but it works.  Appreciate it so much!

Answer (score 0):

your quotation marks are out of order. and why do you need an onClick if you have a href? try this:

```
order: '<a href="http://google.com">order now</a>'
```

or this

```
order : '<a href="#" onClick="location.href=\"http://google.com\"">order now</a>'
```

i just had a look at your site, and it seems that the `order` property is not present. here is an example of how exaclty it should look like this. also mind the position of the curly braces, the `oder` line has to be inside.

```
1: {
  name: 'Bar Soap',
  scent: 'Cucumber &amp; Oatmeal, Patchouli, Peppermint, Frankincense, Holiday, Coffee     &amp; Hazelnut, Apple, and more',
  size: '1 bar',
  price: '3.<span class="small">95</span>',
  short_desc: 'An innovative and moisturizing way to keep shower time fun.',
  desc: 'Since we all love being happy naked, why not keep it that way? Treat yourself  to scrumptious skincare with Naked Bar, an innovative and moisturizing way to keep shower time fun.',
  order: '<a href="/order.php">order now</a>'
},
```

Comment: I tried multiple versions of what you suggested and still no luck, just as described above.  Not sure what I'm missing but your answers echo what I thought should make it work.

Comment: It would help if you could give us a larger portion oft the code

Answer (score 0):

The quotation marks are causing your problems.

```
{
  name: 'Bar Soap',
  scent: 'Cucumber &amp; Oatmeal, Patchouli, Peppermint, Frankincense, Holiday, Coffee &amp; Hazelnut, Apple, and more',
  size: '1 bar',
  price: '3.<span class="small">95</span>',
  short_desc: 'An innovative and moisturizing way to keep shower time fun.',
  desc: 'Since we all love being happy naked, why not keep it that way? Treat yourself to scrumptious skincare with Naked Bar, an innovative and moisturizing way to keep shower time fun.',
  order_url: 'http://google.com'
}
```

Then, do something like this:

```
for (var i in wines) {
      _ += '<li id="wines-'+i+'"><h2>'+wines[i].name+'</h2>'+
        '<div class="lbl"><label>Scent:</label><span>'+wines[i].scent+'</span></div>'+
        '<div class="lbl"><label>Size:</label><span>'+wines[i].size+'</span></div>'+
        '<div class="img"></div>'+
        '<div class="line"></div>'+
        '<div class="short-desc">'+wines[i].short_desc+'</div>'+
        '<div class="price">$'+wines[i].price+'</div>'+
      '</li>';
      __ += '<li id="wine-list-'+i+'">'+wines[i].name+',</li>';
      full += '<div id="wine-info-'+i+'" class="wine-info transition-05"><h2>'+wines[i].name+'</h2><h4></h4>'+
        '<div class="line"></div>'+
        '<div class="price">$'+wines[i].price+'</div>'+
        '<div class="lbl"><label>Scent:</label><span>'+wines[i].scent+'</span></div>'+
        '<div class="lbl"><label>Size:</label><span>'+wines[i].size+'</span></div>'+
        '<div class="img"></div>'+
        '<div class="bottle-x"></div>'+
        '<div class="desc">'+wines[i].desc+'</div>'+
        '<a href="'+wines[i].order_url+'"><div class="order"></div></a>'+
      '</div>';
    }
```

Also, don't forget to define the "order" attribute for all of your items.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I have added this to my code and no dice.  This was along the lines of what I thought should happen but I'm still stumped.

Comment: do you have the site up on a public server somewhere to see what's going on?

Comment: The value is coming through correctly. I would modify your JS code a bit to see it in action. I'll edit my answer here to give you an idea.

Comment: As Grant Kiely suggests in his last comment, adding the z-index:10 will bring the link to the top. You'll still want to do something about the actual link once the user can click on it correctly.